# Check if function exists in other javascript module

Tags: javascript, module

I have a web page that loads two javascript modules:`<script type="module>`. I want, in one module to check if a function exists in the other. I can see no way to do this. The firefox debugger identifies the functions in the module where I'm checking, but I can find no way to examine the functions in the other. Is there some way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Each module has its own top-level scope](https://javascript.info/modules-intro). In other words, top-level variables and functions from a module are not seen in other scripts.

Comment: Damn! I had suspected that this was the case for quite a while, but this is the first time I've seen an article about it. I wonder if this will ever be addressed by the W3C or whoever is responsible. Thank you, Dr. Nugent, for your, quick, complete and very useful reply.